# Can we add any attributes to any XHTML Tag through Javascript ? for example title in <a title="text>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

For some reason I can't edit XHTML source. Can we add any attributes to any XHTML Tag through Javascript, for example title in  `<a title="text">`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: 9 times out of 10, if you "can't edit the source" then you really need to fix that problem, not work around it. A JS solution will be less reliable, probably introduce usability gaps, and be search engine unfriendly.

Comment: How can you add additional Javascript to the page but not be able to edit it? Please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There is no need to break out the jQuery for something so very simple. Also avoid `setAttribute` in general as there are problems with it in IE (not for the `title` attribute, but for many others).

Instead just use the perfectly normal [DOM Level 1 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-78276800) property:

```
link.title= 'text';
```

So eg. if the link you wanted to change was `<a href="..." id="foo">`:

```
document.getElementById('foo').title= 'text';
```

Comment: Thank you for that, much as I love a good api, its less code and way less overhead (in this instance) to just do the raw js.

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery there's the attr() methiod that allows you to do that: http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr

HTML:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
$("a").attr("title","my title");
```

Comment: can search engine and screen reader can read if we addt horugh this way?

Comment: It will be in the JavaScript source. It won't be in the HTML source.

Search engines do not execute JavaScript. Screen readers read whatever is on the page — so it depends on the browser supporting JS and having it turned on (a significant number of screen reader users disable JS as a lot of badly written JS causes them problems).

Comment: my problem is i have 100 images on page and i want to add different title to each image.How can i do this?

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, David's right, if you look up the page's source code, it won't appear.

Comment: @Jitendra: If it's just a matter of displaying a tooltip over the link, you can use this javascript solution; if it's for SEO purposes, then you should edit the source code directly.

Comment: @Jitendra: You should add the appropriate attribute in the server-side code that outputs HTML. Or, if you've already generated HTML and want to modify it before sending it to the browser, use a DOM parser and loop through the `a` links to add attributes.

<http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/> PHP implementation of jQuery
<http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack> HTML Agility Pack for .NET

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes you can.

On the question: *How to do it?* See documentation on [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SetAttribute) method.

Comment: -1, which I'll gladly remove if you edit your answer to tell him how.

Comment: Maybe it´s a pointer so he one day learn to ask proper questions.

Comment: What's wrong with his question as he originally asked it? Yes, technically the question stated "can you", when he meant "how do you", but it's hardly difficult to work out what he meant.

Comment: If you followed the OPs other questions on SO up until now you also should be disillusioned.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery I believe it is faily easy to do

[Here is the related section in Jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the DOM.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml